# google script ReferenceError: "date" is not defined. (line 13, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I can't figure out why I get this error.  The sheet is found here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gBXtHjEhnNSEkJYq2upCWtwkj1ZLWiUYv6KSuMH8Nds/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the first part of the script where it seems to hang up.  The last line is line 13 referenced in the error message.

```
function pushToCalendar() {
    //spreadsheet variables   
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var headerRows = 1;
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = range.getValues();
    for (var i in data) {
        if (i < headerRows) continue;
        var row = data[i]
        var tstart = new Date(row[8]);
        tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because getDate() only works with date object, and 'date' is not defined as a Date object in your present code. Use any Date object, or you can do in this way, `tstart.setDate((new Date()).getDate());`

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I changed the code:
    
tstart.setDate(new Date.getDate());   

Now I get this: "Execution failed: TypeError: (class)@634baebc is not a function, it is undefined. (line 13, file "Code") [0.45 seconds total runtime]"

Comment: I went a different route and was able to accomplish what I wanted.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You got an error because there is a typo mistake. `It's not new Date.getDate()`, but it's `new Date().getDate()`

Comment: I found some script that showed another way of creating the event.  And so I was able to delete that tstart section.  I'll update that dummy sheet so anyone can check it out if their interested.  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score -2):

I went a different route and was able to accomplish what I wanted.

Comment: @Luke: It would be more helpful for future viewers if you shared the "different route" you took.