# "ReferenceError: DATE is not defined" in AppScript for Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out how to add a new event to my calendar. So far all the tutorials I've followed use `new Date(date)` to define the dates of their events, but when I try to do the same, it gives me the error:

> ReferenceError: DATE is not defined

This is my code:

```
function LGBT_Holidays() {
  let calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("a3e1a2415c1dad9d1a8ac46ce42bc8d8a9c94ee35f77397a64854eeee8cfed61@group.calendar.google.com")
  calendar.createAllDayEvent("Transgender Awareness Week", new DATE("November 13, 2022"), new DATE("November 19, 2022"), {description:"A week to raise awareness of transgender people."})
}
```

Every time I Google how to add an event to Google Calendar, it gives me something similar.

Comment: new DATE() should be new Date()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
new DATE("November 13, 2022")
```

use

```
new Date("November 13, 2022")
```

The above, because `DATE` is not the same than `Date`. In Google Sheets it doesn't matter if formula functions are wrote using lower case, upper case or a combination of both but Google Apps Script / JavaScript are case sensitive, this means that it's important to use upper case and lower case characters properly.

**Related**

- [google script ReferenceError: "date" is not defined. (line 13, file "Code")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27514290/1595451)